# Center RadRibbonBar Image Buttons

Tags: html, telerik

I have a RadRibbonBar on a RadWindow and 4 groups within the first tab. I want to center the 4 groupings in the tab section within the RadWindow. Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What is the declaration you have? Have you tried inspecting the rendered HTML to see what the tabs render as and perhaps try a margin: auto for their wrapper? The ribbon bar is not supposed to center the tabs, however, so this may not be possible.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. I guess I'll just have to use a different control. Thanks for the help!